# Proving $2\cos \alpha\sin(\alpha N)=\sin(\alpha(N-1))$, where $\alpha=\pi k/(N+1)$ for integer $k$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to prove: 
>   $$2\cos \alpha \sin(\alpha N)=\sin(\alpha(N-1)) \quad\text{where}\quad \alpha=\frac{\pi k}{N+1}$$
>   with $k$ an integer.

Some common trig identities don't work.

---

The problem arises from the following exercise. In particular, showing that the equality in the last component of the vector. (In this exercise, $\Delta x = 1/(N+1)$.)

[image]

Comment: Add the first two equation given here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: If you're trying to show that the relation holds for all values, then you're going to have a bad time. Consider: When $N=1$, the right-hand side is zero, while the left-hand side may not be.

Comment: @Blue let's say $N > 1$

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(\alpha(N-1))+\sin(\alpha(N+1))$?

Comment: Okay, consider $N=2$. Then the left-hand side is $2\cos\alpha \sin 2\alpha$, which is zero when $\alpha=\pi/2$; the right-hand side is $\sin\alpha$, which is not zero for $\alpha=\pi/2$. ... In general, the expressions simply are not equivalent. ... You mention that "some common trig identities don't work". Please explain what identities you've tried and where they failed; you may already have shown that they aren't equal without realizing it.

Comment: @Blue Hold on going to post a screenshot in the question

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no I had to proof that too but already got that one

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I posted to source

Comment: The problem is the last entry of the vector

Comment: Is $\Delta x = \dfrac{1}{N+1}$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 yes

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising: The dependence of $\alpha$ on $N$ makes this work. I've edited the problem to make this apparent. Please double-check my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$2\sin p \cos q = \sin(p+q) + \sin(p-q) \tag{1}$$
with $p = \alpha N$ and $q = \alpha$ gives
$$2\sin(\alpha N)\cos\alpha = \sin(\alpha N + \alpha) + \sin(\alpha N - \alpha) \tag{2}$$
But $$\alpha N + \alpha = \alpha (N+1) = \frac{\pi k}{N+1}(N+1) = \pi k \tag{3}$$
Since $k$ is an integer, $\sin \pi k = 0$; thus, the first term on the right-hand side of (2) vanishes, leaving the desired relation. $\square$